# Callback to datatable when user changes a content of cell

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to know if there any js_on_change parameter with which I could track an event that user changes a content of any cell in datatable.

For example, I have this datatable and vbar-plot and I would like that xlabels would've changed right after I've updated their names in datatable.
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS

cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3]))
dt = DataTable(columns=[TableColumn(title='X', field='x')], source=cds, editable=True)

cds.js_on_change('patching', CustomJS(code="console.log(cb_obj);"))

show(dt)
```

Comment: Thank you!
And is there any way to delete entire row from datatable (with option editable=True)?

Comment: There is not. Bokeh data sources are column-based. To "delete" a row, you would need to delete the item from every column individually in a copy of the `.data` object, and then set the `.data` property to the new value.

Comment: @Higem as the answer resolves your actual OP question, could you accept?

Comment: Is there a server side version of this too? cds.on_change('data', _, old, new, func) doesn't trigger when a value in a grid cell is changed and cds.on_change('patching') raises an error claiming that no property 'patching' exists.

Comment: It is possible but less trivial, you have to use `Document.on_change` and `isinstance`. If you ask a new SO question, I can answer it with proper code.